# htaccess rewrite to already rewritten url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've built a website creator but am having problems with the domains.
The client website urls are as follows: http://www.maindomain.com/userdomain.com (already using mod_rewrite).

I am now trying to point a top level domain at the already rewritten url. Sadly that doesn't seem to work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(ww+\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %2 !^maindomain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%2/$1 [L]
```

Funnily enough it works fine as a redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(ww+\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %2 !^maindomain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.maindomain.com/%2/$1 [L]
```

This isn't an really an option though as visitors shouldn't be able to see my domain.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use mod_proxy [P Flag].

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can't believe it was something that simple! The only problem is now its still loading all links on the page from maindomain.com rather than userdomain.com whic is causing ajax errors (Origin http://userdomain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.)

Comment: Hi Adam, AJAX calls are only allowed within the same domain. Call a php script with file_get_contents from the other domain.

Comment: Hey, thanks again. If I do a redirect like RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/index.php?userid=123 [L] it also rewrites all the URLs on the page or isn't that possible when using proxy?